# Module not found - import { ReactBricks } from 'react-bricks/frontend'

Tags: r, reactjs, npm

I am creating an app with react bricks,
Everything was running smoothly until I wanted to import icons and then I ran an authentication, and now one of the main frontend packages is not found in my app.

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-bricks/frontend'
  1 | import { useState } from 'react'
> 2 | import { ReactBricks } from 'react-bricks/frontend'
  3 | import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
  4 | import config from '../react-bricks/config'
```

I have uninstalled icon. I've tried running the following commands:

```
npm install --save react-bricks
```

```
npm install --save react-bricks-ui
```

I've also deleted and reinstalled `node_modules`.

This is my `package.json`:

```json
{
   "dependencies":{
      "next":"^12.3.1",
      "prism-theme-night-owl":"^1.4.0",
      "prismjs":"^1.29.0",
      "react":"^18.2.0",
      "react-bricks":"^2.3.16",
      "react-bricks-ui":"^0.1.17",
      "react-dom":"^18.2.0",
      "react-slick":"^0.29.0"
   },
   "devDependencies":{
      "@types/node":"^18.8.2",
      "@types/react":"^18.0.21",
      "autoprefixer":"^10.4.12",
      "concurrently":"^7.4.0",
      "postcss":"^8.4.17",
      "tailwindcss":"^3.1.8",
      "typescript":"^4.8.4"
   }
}
```

Comment: Delete node_modules and re-install all packages?

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` file?

Comment: },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^12.3.1",
    "prism-theme-night-owl": "^1.4.0",
    "prismjs": "^1.29.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bricks": "^2.3.16",
    "react-bricks-ui": "^0.1.17",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.8.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
    "concurrently": "^7.4.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.17",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}